# Why is this partition marked as active despite not having the currently running windows on it?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

My old HDR has not only been running full - reaching it's maximum of 500~ GB, but it's also been running through a lot of time. This HDD is very very old and has been running poorly.

So, to upgrade, I decided to treat myself to a new 1TB HDD.

I wanted to keep my old files though and still use my old HDD to store photos and the like, given while slow, it was still running just fine. Perfect to store some files that are on the "might wanna keep/very rarely used" pile.

Either way... my plan was to:
- Install Windows 10 on the new HDD, boot the PC from there and then essentially slowly migrate the files I need from the old HDD.
- Once I am done, format the old HDD and use it as storage.

I turned the PC off, removed the old HDD given in the past I had a lot of issues trying to install windows 10 on a PC that had multiple HDDs attached to it, put in the new one and installed windows 10 on it. No issues. After putting the old one back in again and peeking into Disk Management, I however catch that despite the current HDD being marked as C: and having System,Boot,Page File,Active,Crash Dump etc. on it alongside of the Windows Logo next to it on "This PC" - the old HDD is marked as Active aswell!

Questions:

- Why is the old HDD marked as Active? I thought Active meant that windows was running on it, but all signs point to the Windows of the new HDD currently running, especially the new HDD being marked as active, too...
- Is this even a problem in the first place?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "This PC" - the old HDD is marked as Active as well!" Because it is marked as active and will stay that way until you use diskpart in command prompt to remove the active mark.

Comment: So it's not a huge issue? What does it being marked as Active do if it isnt the version of Windows being used/shown as the one being used in "This PC"?

Comment: It just means that there is a partition on there that can be booted, it doesn't necessarily mean it is active right now.

Comment: Thank you! I was fearing I did something wrong....

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1441183/what-is-the-purpose-of-mbr-active-partition